# How to print all selected checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to print all values that I tick in the checkbox if I checked more than 1 checkbox. However, it only print the first value that I checked.  [If I checked more than 1 checkbox in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCdOP.png) [It only printed one value from the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYDzw.png) Thanks in advance

```
 // HTML code    
<strong>IT Skills:&emsp;</strong><br><br>
<div class="checkboxlist"  id="skills">
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Programming/Application Development" class="chk">&nbsp;Programming/Application Development&emsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Project Management" class="chk">&nbsp;Project Management&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Helpdesk/Technical Support" class="chk">&nbsp;Helpdesk/ Technical Support&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Security/Compliance Governance" class="chk">&nbsp;Security/ Compliance Governance&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Web Development" class="chk">&nbsp;Web Development&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Database Administration" class="chk">&nbsp;Database Administration&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Business Intelligence/Analytics" class="chk">&nbsp;Business Intelligence/ Analytics&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Mobile Applications and Device Management" class="chk">&nbsp;Mobile Applications and Device Management&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Networking" class="chk">&nbsp;Networking&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Big Data" class="chk">&nbsp;Big Data&emsp;<br>
</div>
<span class="error_form" id="skills_error_message"></span>

 //jQuery code
 function check_skills(){
    var skill = [];
    if (skills == 'checked') {
       $("#skills_error_message").hide();
       $("#skills").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
     } else {
       $("#skills_error_message").html("Please select a skill!");
       $("#skills_error_message").show();
       $("#skills").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
       error_skills = true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found out the answer to my question. It turned that I need to add [] in name in every checkbox. So when I added [] to skills, it printed all the checked value from the checkbox. By the way, thanks for everyone who've helped me.

```
<strong>IT Skills:&emsp;</strong><br><br>
<div class="checkboxlist"  id="skills">
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Programming/Application Development" class="chk">&nbsp;Programming/Application Development&emsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Project Management" class="chk">&nbsp;Project Management&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Helpdesk/Technical Support" class="chk">&nbsp;Helpdesk/ Technical Support&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Security/Compliance Governance" class="chk">&nbsp;Security/ Compliance Governance&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Web Development" class="chk">&nbsp;Web Development&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Database Administration" class="chk">&nbsp;Database Administration&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Business Intelligence/Analytics" class="chk">&nbsp;Business Intelligence/ Analytics&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Mobile Applications and Device Management" class="chk">&nbsp;Mobile Applications and Device Management&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Networking" class="chk">&nbsp;Networking&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Big Data" class="chk">&nbsp;Big Data&emsp;<br>
</div>
<span class="error_form" id="skills_error_message"></span>

    [skills] => Array
    (
        [0] => Web Development
        [1] => Business Intelligence/Analytics
        [2] => Networking
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `jQuery :checked` selector

```js
//jQuery code
function check_skills() {
  var favorite = [];
  $.each($("input[name='skills']:checked"), function() {
    favorite.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(favorite)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>IT Skills:&emsp;</strong><br><br>
<div class="checkboxlist" id="skills">
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Programming/Application Development" class="chk">&nbsp;Programming/Application Development&emsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Project Management" class="chk">&nbsp;Project Management&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Helpdesk/Technical Support" class="chk">&nbsp;Helpdesk/ Technical Support&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Security/Compliance Governance" class="chk">&nbsp;Security/ Compliance Governance&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Web Development" class="chk">&nbsp;Web Development&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Database Administration" class="chk">&nbsp;Database Administration&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Business Intelligence/Analytics" class="chk">&nbsp;Business Intelligence/ Analytics&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Mobile Applications and Device Management" class="chk">&nbsp;Mobile Applications and Device Management&emsp;<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Networking" class="chk">&nbsp;Networking&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Big Data" class="chk">&nbsp;Big Data&emsp;<br>
</div>
<span class="error_form" id="skills_error_message"></span>
<button onclick="check_skills()">
Check
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, I've tried using your code and it only printed on the console log not at the array list. It only printed one value at the array list even though I checked more than one checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like below

```
function check_skills(){

    var selected_skills = $('.chk:checked');

    if (selected_skills.length > 0)
    {
        $("#skills_error_message").hide();
        $("#skills").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
    }
    else {
        $("#skills_error_message").html("Please select a skill!");
        $("#skills_error_message").show();
        $("#skills").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
        error_skills = true;
    }
}
```

Using the selector `:checked` along with the `.chk` class to get all the checked check boxes every time the function is called.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've tried using your code and the problem is still same where the array list only printed one value from the checkbox even though I checked more than one checkbox. It won't display all values that I checked